# How do you run entire python script without closing imported scripts?

Tags: python

I have a python script and I imported another script (a simple GUI window) using:

```
import gui
```

So when I run the code, the GUI pops up and I need to close the GUI in order for the script to continue executing.

Is there any way to run the entire script while keeping the GUI window open the whole time?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this with threading in which the GUI is running off a child thread while the rest of the script runs on the main thread.